# how to connect Azure AD B2C to Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

As I am working on SSO, I have my on-premised application on aadb2c and my cloud application is registered on AAD, is there any way to migrate consumer identities by using custom identity provider or any other way

Comment: Can you please make sure of the quesion it should be on-Prem Azure AD application and app is registered in Azure AD B2C.?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ADFS to consume on prem AD identities. You can add ADFS as identity provider in B2C. You can also sync on-prem identities to AAD and add your AAD directory as identity provider.